# NSString from NSData is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsdata, dispatch

I try to get an NSString from NSData but I get a nil value.
This is my code:

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.message.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

When I log `self.message.data` I get:

```
Printing description of self->_message->_data:
<OS_dispatch_data: data[0x17e48290] = { leaf, size = 331233, buf = 0x3aac000 }>
```

That means my data is not nil…

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is this data coming from and in which format is this data sent?

Comment: What is outputted if you do `NSLog(@"Class of self->_message->_data: %@", NSStringFromClass([self->_message->_data class]));`?

Comment: The `initWithData:encoding:` method expected an `NSData` object. What is your `self.message.data` object?

Comment: Interestingly there's also another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434245/how-to-convert-os-dispatch-data-5018112-bytes-into-nsdata-to-put-into-uiimag) around this `OS_dispatch_data`! (Not that I'm saying this is a duplicate!)

Comment: Just noticed my data isn't a regular NSData as I thought. It is OS_Dispatch_Data. What is it?

Comment: @NimrodShai see [this question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152851/how-to-convert-dispatch-data-t-to-nsdata) for more information about `OS_dispatch_data` :)

Comment: try using `po [self.message.data description]` in the debugger to get a printed description of the data. That will give insight into whether the data might be in the proper format to create a string out of...

Comment: what's the encoding of the text in the NSData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answer to your question in comments:
`OS_dispatch_data` is `dispatch_data_t` which has toll-free bridging with NSData on iOS 7 and Mavericks. You can simply cast it to `NSData *`.

So, in your case you can write:

```
NSData *dataCast = self.message.data;
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataCast encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And now you get the correct string!

In my case it appeared, when `AFNetworking` cast internal `NSMutableData` to `NSData`.

And this simple cast helps me.

---

**UPD:** As **@Daij-Djan** mentioned: If it's not works - try to check your text encoding.

For example if you're yousing `NSURLSessionTask`:

```
NSURLSessionTask *task; // Your NSURLSessionTask
NSString *encoding = [[task response] textEncodingName];
```

In your case (`NSUTF8StringEncoding`) it should be **"utf-8"**.

Comment: IF the encoding of the text is UTF8

Comment: @Daij-Djan of course. But question is how convert `OS_dispatch_data` to `NSData`. And I believe that we know the encoding that we use.

Comment: the question is 'NSString from NSData is nil' -- and what do you mean 'we know'

Comment: btw I up voted you because you finally wrote that dispatch data is just an internal representation for NSData - the comments were weird :)

Comment: though as the code you provide is 100% the op's code I guess it is the encoding

Comment: @Daij-Djan w\o this redundant cast I also get the `nil` string. And this simple cast solve my problem. I  don't know why. Complier bug?.. :)

Comment: @Daij-Djan Ok, I update answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try UTF-16 encoding instead.  It may be an error converting to UTF-8 if any data in there is not recognized.